# Store Java Class in DB and Load it Use it Destroy it

Tags: java, database

Is possible and how Store Java Classes in DB and then Load class from DB and call loaded Class with some arguments?

Comment: Yes it is possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Java Compiler API to compile it at runtime. See [here](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/12/13/java-se-6-compiler-api/) for an example

In order to load classes at runtime, you can either use an `URLClassLoader` if you can specify the location of the bytecode with a URL, or use [ClassLoader.defineClass](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass%28java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) and supply the bytecode as an array of bytes.

> Make sure that your class is known at compile time and you can do it
>   with the help of interface.